# Using partition clause in the subquery

Tags: teradata, partition

Am new to TD and need some help regarding the below query.

We have a query of which the from clause looks like this:

```
`*sel *
FROM 
V_ACOR  ACOR,
V_ORTR ORTR,
V_MSAC MSAC,
V_MSRC MSRC,
V_REOR REOR
WHERE 
ACOR.ORDER_ID = ORTR.ORDER_ID
AND 
(SELECT MIN(ARRIVE_DATE_ORTR)  AS ARRIVE_DATE FROM V_ORTR )
BETWEEN  MSAC.BEGIN_DATE AND  MSAC.END_DATE
AND 
(SELECT MIN(ARRIVE_DATE_ORTR)  AS ARRIVE_DATE FROM V_ORTR )
BETWEEN  MSRC.BEGIN_DATE AND  MSRC.END_DATE
AND  
(SELECT MIN(ARRIVE_DATE_REOR)  AS ARRIVE_DATE FROM V_REOR )
BETWEEN  MSAC.BEGIN_DATE AND  MSAC.END_DATE
AND 
(SELECT MIN(ARRIVE_DATE_REOR)  AS ARRIVE_DATE FROM V_REOR )
BETWEEN  MSRC.BEGIN_DATE AND  MSRC.END_DATE*`
```

Now the problem is, the MIN(ARRIVE_DATE) in all the cases, giving me the min value on all entries. Our requirement was to get the min date based on the ORDER_ID. So we tried with the below in the place of MIN(ARRIVE_DATE):

```
`(SELECT ARRIVE_DATE FROM V_ORTR  
qualify row_NUMBER() over (PARTITION  by ORDER_ID order by ARRIVE_DATE ASC) = 1
)BETWEEN  MSAC.BEGIN_DATE AND  MSAC.END_DATE`
```

This is showing an error:

**Ordered Analytical Functions are not allowed in sub queries.**

We tried with the below as well:

```
`*sel * from 
(
sel A.*
from (sel * FROM V_ORTR
QUALIFY row_NUMBER() over (PARTITION  by ORTR.ORDER_ID order by ORTR.ARRIVE_DATE ASC)=1
) A ,
sel B.*
from (sel * FROM V_REOR
QUALIFY row_NUMBER() over (PARTITION  by REOR.ORDER_ID order by REOR.ARRIVE_DATE_ORDR_TR ASC)=1 
)B ,
V_ACOR,
V_MSAC,
V_MSRC
WHERE 
ACOR.ORDER_ID_ORDR = A.ORDER_ID
AND A.ARRIVE_DATE_ORTR BETWEEN MSAC.BEGIN_DATE AND MSAC.END_DATE
AND A.ARRIVE_DATE_ORTR BETWEEN MSRC.BEGIN_DATE AND MSRC.END_DATE
AND B.ARRIVE_DATE_REOR BETWEEN MSAC.BEGIN_DATE AND MSAC.END_DATE
AND B.ARRIVE_DATE_REOR BETWEEN MSRC.BEGIN_DATE AND MSRC.END_DATE
)*`
```

This is also giving below error:

**Syntax error, expected something like a name or a Unicode delimited identifier or '(' between '.' and the 'sel' keyword.**

Comment: Which DBMS (and version) are you using? Postgres? Oracle? SQL Server? DB2?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. We are using Teradata version 13

Answer (score 4):

You can't use OLAP functions in subqueries because they might be correlated. There's a trick to handle this specific error: move it into a Derived Table within a subquery (there's no way to correlate into a Derived Table):

```
WHERE   
 (
   SELECT * 
   FROM
    (
      SELECT ARRIVE_DATE 
      FROM V_ORTR  
      QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() 
      OVER (PARTITION  BY ORDER_ID ORDER BY ARRIVE_DATE ASC) = 1
    ) AS dt
 ) BETWEEN  MSAC.BEGIN_DATE AND  MSAC.END_DATE
```

But this will not work because it's returning multiple rows with a

> "3669 More than one value was returned by a subquery"

And your second try has some syntax errors. Plus you don't need to nest the OLAP function in a Derived Table because it's already in a Derived Table. Some (or better a lot) people call a "Derived Table" a "subquery", in Oracle it's a "Inlie View", so the naming might be confusing, too:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
 (
   SELECT * FROM V_ORTR
   QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION  BY ORTR.ORDER_ID ORDER BY ORTR.ARRIVE_DATE ASC) = 1
 ) A ,
 (
   SELECT * FROM V_REOR
   QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION  BY REOR.ORDER_ID ORDER BY REOR.ARRIVE_DATE_ORDR_TR ASC) = 1 
 ) B,
   V_ACOR,
   V_MSAC,
   V_MSRC
WHERE 
  ACOR.ORDER_ID_ORDR = A.ORDER_ID
AND A.ARRIVE_DATE_ORTR BETWEEN MSAC.BEGIN_DATE AND MSAC.END_DATE
AND A.ARRIVE_DATE_ORTR BETWEEN MSRC.BEGIN_DATE AND MSRC.END_DATE
AND B.ARRIVE_DATE_REOR BETWEEN MSAC.BEGIN_DATE AND MSAC.END_DATE
AND B.ARRIVE_DATE_REOR BETWEEN MSRC.BEGIN_DATE AND MSRC.END_DATE
```

But are you shure these are all join conditions? I would expect some additional conditions, at least A.ORDER_ID = B.ORDER_ID

Comment: Thanks for the reply. We have couple of more joins. and yes, a join over OEDER_ID is also there.